# re.search() TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, regex

The code below works as intended if I do `re.search("(\d+)x"`.

However if I add an alternative search `re.search("(\d+)x|x(\d+)"` I get:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Code:

```
fundleverage = None
regex_fundleverage = None
regex_fundleverage = re.search(r"(\d+)x|x(\d+)", instrument_name, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if funddirection == "Long" and not regex_fundleverage == None:
    fundleverage = "+" + regex_fundleverage.group(1) + "00"
if funddirection == "Short" and not regex_fundleverage == None:
    fundleverage = "-" + regex_fundleverage.group(1) + "00"
print "Fundleverage: %s" % fundleverage
```

The error is of course due to that I try to concatenate str `"+"` and `"00"` with `None`.

My question is why selecting `group(1)`works when there is only one lookup in `re.search()`, but does not work if there are two alternative lookups.

The string it's searching does not contain both alternatives `"(\d+)x"` and `"x(\d+)"`, only one is possible.

Example str:

```
"Boost LevDAX 3x Daily ETP"
"ComStage LevDAX x2 UCITS ETF"
```

Comment: Don't use the above regex in `re.search` if you want two outputs  since search will stop once it finds the first match.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Only one of the alternatives are present in the string. Am I understanding it right that it will only "look" for the first alternative but not for the second, thus making it "None" if not present?

Comment: Never compare to None

Comment: If I search for `re.findall` I get: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: `re.findall` will return a list of found items not groups

Comment: Are you trying to extract the `3x` and `x2` or only the numbers `3` and `2` ?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Only numbers `3` and `2` and then concatenate with `+` and `00` so it becomes `+300` and `+200`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
regex_fundleverage = re.findall('(?<=x)\d+|\d+(?=x)',instrument_name, flags=re.IGNORECASE) 

if funddirection == "Long" and regex_fundleverage:
    fundleverage = "+" + regex_fundleverage[0] + "00"

if funddirection == "Short" and regex_fundleverage:
    fundleverage = "-" + regex_fundleverage[0] + "00"

print "Fundleverage: %s" % fundleverage
```

Comment: Returns `None`, I'm not sure if the regex finds anything. Will try to find the error.

Comment: It was missing `and not regex_fundleverage = None:`, can you please update your answer? It works now :)

Comment: @Winterflags...Thanks for pointing that out, actually, you can just do `and regex_fundleverage :` (no need for `and not regex_fundleverage == None:`) .. it means: `and if there is anything in regex_fundleverage` and if `regex_fundleverage` was empty it will be `False` .. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks :) I kept `fundleverage = None` and `regex_fundleverage = None` in front of your code and it works now. I will go with this solution since it was really closest to the original implentation, but big thanks to everyone who assisted me!

Answer (score 2):

I did use `re.findall`

```
x = re.findall(r'(?<=x)\d+|\d+(?=x)', s)
```

Then get the first element by specifying the first index like `x[0]` . You won't get `None` value.

**or**

You may also use `re.search` function without capturing groups.

```
re.search(r'(?<=x)\d+|\d+(?=x)', s).group()
```

I think you want tjis,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Boost LevDAX 3x Daily ETP"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+(?=x)|(?<=x)\d+', r'+\g<0>00', s)
'Boost LevDAX +300x Daily ETP'
```

**OR**

```
>>> s = "Boost LevDAX 3x Daily ETP"
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)x|x(\d+)', lambda m: '+'+m.group(1)+'00' if m.group(1) else '+' + m.group(2) + '00', s)
'Boost LevDAX +300 Daily ETP'
>>> s = "ComStage LevDAX x2 UCITS ETF"
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)x|x(\d+)', lambda m: '+'+m.group(1)+'00' if m.group(1) else '+' + m.group(2) + '00', s)
'ComStage LevDAX +200 UCITS ETF'
```

According to your comment, there is only one `nox` or `xno` present in your input strings. If yes, then you may try this,

```
>>> s = "ComStage LevDAX x2 UCITS ETF"
>>> fundleverage = re.sub(r'.*(?:(\d+)x|x(\d+)).*', lambda m: '+'+m.group(1)+'00' if m.group(1) else '+' + m.group(2) + '00', s)
>>> print fundleverage
```

Comment: Hmm. The `re.sub` solution correctly substitutes to  `+300` but keeps the entire string `"Boost LevDAX +300 Daily ETP"`. It should pass on only  `"+300"` to variable `fundleverage`. Other than that, it seems good.

Answer (score 2):

if you were to pass just the first string your program would work ok. but when you pass the second string, the second group is matched. group(1) is None, while group(2) is 2.

I would rewrite your code to separate the two subexpression and use an `if` statement to decide which one matches.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to check if the string is in your desired form , and if it does then just extract the number you want by using `\d+` since your string can contain only one number as follows:

Notice that the advantage of doing this is it throws an error if the `leverage` is not in desired format like `x3x` in your string

```
import re
fundleverage = None
regex_fundleverage = None
funddirection = "Long"
instrument_name = "ComStage LevDAX 3x UCITS ETF"
regex_fundleverage = re.search(r"(\b\d+x|x\d+\b)", instrument_name, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if  regex_fundleverage:
    regex_fundleverage = re.search(r"(\d+)", regex_fundleverage.group(0), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(regex_fundleverage.group(0))
if funddirection == "Long" and not regex_fundleverage == None:
    fundleverage = "+" + regex_fundleverage.group(1) + "00"
if funddirection == "Short" and not regex_fundleverage == None:
    fundleverage = "-" + regex_fundleverage.group(1) + "00"
print "Fundleverage: %s" % fundleverage
```

Comment: @Winterflags , Nice :)

Comment: @Winterflags also consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied :)